# Assign a value to an active record relation field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

This is my first model :

```
class Sender < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :letters
end
```

and this is the Second one:

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender
end
```

I find a letter like this in rails Consol :

```
@letter = Letter.where(id: 378)
```

the result is :

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Letter id: 378, indicator: "95/2", classification: "aa", urgency: "aa", package_id: nil, registrar_id: 0, user_id: nil, subset_type: "official", created_at: "2016-11-10 06:02:14", updated_at: "2016-11-10 06:02:14", sender_id: nil>]>
```

as you can see the **sender_id** is **nil**.
The thing I want is to set a value to the sender_id like this :

```
@letter.sender_id = 12
```

but I got this ***error***:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sender_id=' for #<Letter::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004cc96c0>
Did you mean?  send_later
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:123:in `method_missing'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:93:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):19
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Letter.where(id: 378)
```

returns a ***collection*** of records matching the query condition. And of course, you do not have a method `sender_id=` for an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

What you want instead is a single record, which can be get by either

```
@letter = Letter.where(id: 378).first
```

or

```
@letter = Letter.find(id: 378)
```

Now, having a single record, you can update it's `sender_id` attribute:

```
@letter.update(sender_id: 12)
```

Comment: Thanks a million @AndreyDeineko :) It Was My mistake to put Where instead of find.

Comment: @AfsaneFadaei I noticed, you never accepted an answer to any of your questions. Please, walk through your past questions and make sure to checkmark the answers, that solved your problems, this way you let the community know that the issue is solved and, also, reward the effort of the user who has given this answer.

Comment: Oh you're right.Going to do it right now.BTW thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
@letter = Letter.find_by_id(378)

# or

@letter = Letter.find(378)
```

because

```
@letter = Letter.where(id: 378)
```

will return you an array of records

Comment: Oh Thanks a million @Deepak :) It Was My mistake :)))))